# How to authenticate using ember.js and django?

Tags: python, django, authentication, ember.js, django-rest-framework

I am new in ember.js and django.

I have done with django API using rest-framwork authentication means at the back-end side my api is working fine with authentication.

Now I have to authenticate from front end side using ember. Please tell me how to do ?

Comment: You did not even try... why would someone do your work? please come back with some code...

Comment: Hey. I have tried using this videos http://www.embercasts.com/ But i am not getting.

Comment: Authentication is not trivial and there is no out-of-box solution for ember+django auth, at least not yet. If you need that done it will take some work, could be a challenge if you are new to both ember.js and django. Perhaps once you've figured it out you can blog about the solution and help others in future. Meantime, I suggest posting again with specific questions about what you didn't understand from the embercasts.com video.